# Unable to see preview in android studio in Electric eel update

Tags: android, layout, render, preview

Error getting as Render Problem, tried with lot of online suggestions but nothing working, can some body please help me on that.[image]

Comment: Can you share what you have tried already?

Comment: I tried everything from google suggestions with changing the Gradle plugin version 7.4.1 and 7.5 in project structure, tried with installing all the android SDK API levels from 28-33. can you please suggest me other than these can I do anything to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to clear Android Studio's cache & restart?

Comment: @gioravered yeah I done that too so many times but no use.